# Moving Title Animation On Banner

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have an animation on the content of my hero image that start from a 3/4th frame. However when titles repeat it again starts from 3/4th frame.

I want that from the second time by the time the last letter is leaving the frame the first letters of the "next" sentence have already started on the other end.
Can you help me with this?

Here is the website link: http://54.91.174.201/

```css
@keyframes home_hero1 {
  0% {
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -4400px;
  }
}

@keyframes home_hero2 {
  0% {
    margin-right: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: -4400px;
  }
}

.heading_h1 {
  font-size: 150px;
  letter-spacing: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-animation: home_hero1 21s linear 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: home_hero1 21s linear 0s infinite;
}

.heading_h2 {
  font-size: 150px;
  letter-spacing: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-animation: home_hero2 23s linear 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: home_hero2 23s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-hero-left">
  <h2 class="heading_h1">
    <span class="underline--magical">98% PLANT & NATURALLY DERIVED INGREDIENTS*</span>
  </h2>
  <h2 class="heading_h2"><span class="underline--magical show-on-scroll">98% PLANT & NATURALLY DERIVED INGREDIENTS*</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```